# Elixir non-blocking threads on a GenServer?

Tags: multithreading, elixir, nonblocking, gen-server

I'm trying to accomplish a simple task but I'm having huge difficulties.

Please suppose I have a `GenServer`, and one of its callbacks is as follows:

```
  @impl true
  def handle_call(:state, _, state) do
    # Something that would require 10 seconds
    newState = do_job()
    {:reply, newState, newState}
  end
```

If I am right, invoking `GenServer.call(:server, :state)` from a client side would block the server for 10 seconds, and then the new state would be returned to the client.

Okey. I want the server to handle this task without being blocked. I've tried using Tasks, but `Task.await/2` and `Task.yield/2` block the server.

I want the server not to block, and after those 10 seconds, receive the result on the client terminal. How would this be possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> If I am right, invoking GenServer.call(:server, :state) from a client
>   side would block the server for 10 seconds, and then the new state
>   would be returned to the client.

Yes.  Elixir does what you tell it to do, and in this line:

```
newState = do_job()
```

you are telling elixir to assign the return value of `do_job()` to the variable `newState`.  The only way elixir can perform that assignment is by getting the return value of `go_job()`....which will take 10 seconds.

> I want the server not to block, and after those 10 seconds, receive
>   the result on the client terminal.

One approach is for the GenServer to `spawn()` a new process to execute the 10 second function and pass the pid of the client to the new process.  When the new process gets the return value from the 10 second function, the new process can `send()` a message to the client using the client pid.

That means the client would need to call `handle_call()` rather than `handle_cast()` because the server's implementation of `handle_cast()` doesn't have a `from` parameter variable containing the client pid.   On the other hand, `handle_call()` *does* receive the client pid in a `from` parameter variable, so the server can pass the client pid to the spawned process.   Note that `spawn()` returns immediately, which means that `handle_call()` can return immediately with a reply like `:working_on_it`.

The next issue is: how will the client know when the new process that the GenServer spawned has finished executing the 10 second function?  The client can't know when some extraneous process on the server has finished executing, so the client needs to wait in a receive until the message arrives from the spawned process. And, if the client is checking for messages in its mailbox, it would be helpful to know who the sender was, which means `handle_call()` should also return the pid of the spawned process to the client.  Another option for the client is to *poll* its mailbox every so often between bouts of doing other work.  To do that, the client can define a receive with a short timeout in an [after clause](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/processes.html#send-and-receive), then call a function in the `after clause` to do some client work, followed by a recursive call to the function containing the receive so that the function checks the mailbox again.

Now what about `Task`?  According to the [Task docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html):

> If you are using async tasks, you **must await** a reply...

Well, then what good is an async task if you must wait? Answer: if a process has *at least two* long running functions it needs to execute, then the process can use `Task.async()` to run all the functions at the same time, rather than executing one function and waiting until it finishes, then executing another function and waiting until it finishes, then executing another one, etc.

But, Task also defines a [start()](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#start/3) function:

> **start(mod, fun, args)**
>
> Starts a task.
>
> This is only used when the task is used for side-effects (i.e. no
>   interest in the returned result) and it should not be linked to the
>   current process.

That sounds like `Task.start()` accomplishes what I described in the first approach.  You need to define `fun` so that it will run the 10 second function, then send a message back to the client after the 10 second function has finished executing (= the *side-effect*).

Below is a simple example of a GenServer that spawns a long running function, which allows the server to remain responsive to other client requests while the long running function executes:

a.exs:

```
defmodule Gen1.Server do
  use GenServer

  @impl true
  def init(init_state) do
    {:ok, init_state}
  end

  def long_func({pid, _ref}) do
    Process.sleep 10_000
    result = :dog
    send(pid, {self(), result})
  end

  @impl true
  def handle_call(:go_long, from, state) do
    long_pid = spawn(Gen1.Server, :long_func, [from])
    {:reply, long_pid, state}
  end
  def handle_call(:other, _from, state) do
    {:reply, :other_stuff, state}
  end

end
```

An iex session will be the client:

```
~/elixir_programs$ iex a.exs
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Interactive Elixir (1.6.6) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)

iex(1)> {:ok, server_pid} = GenServer.start_link(Gen1.Server, [])
{:ok, #PID<0.93.0>}

iex(2)> long_pid = GenServer.call(server_pid, :go_long, 15_000)
#PID<0.100.0>

iex(3)> GenServer.call(server_pid, :other)                       
:other_stuff

iex(4)> receive do                                             
...(4)> {^long_pid, reply} -> reply                            
...(4)> end                                                    
:dog

iex(7)>
```

A variable like `long_pid` will match anything.  To get `long_pid` to match only its current value, you specify `^long_pid` (`^` is called the pin operator).

A GenServer also allows you to block a client's call of `handle_call()` while allowing the server to continue executing.  That's useful if a client is unable to continue until it gets some needed data from the server, but you want the server to remain responsive to other clients.  Here's an example of that:

```
defmodule Gen1.Server do
  use GenServer

  @impl true
  def init(init_state) do
    {:ok, init_state}
  end

  @impl true
  def handle_call(:go_long, from, state) do
    spawn(Gen1.Server, :long_func, [from])
    {:noreply, state}  #The server doesn't send anything to the client, 
                       #so the client's call of handle_call() blocks until 
                       #somebody calls GenServer.reply().
  end

  def long_func(from) do
    Process.sleep 10_000
    result = :dog
    GenServer.reply(from, result) 
  end

end
```

In iex:

```
iex(1)> {:ok, server_pid} = GenServer.start_link(Gen1.Server, [])
{:ok, #PID<0.93.0>}

iex(2)> result = GenServer.call(server_pid, :go_long, 15_000)
...hangs for 10 seconds...   
:dog

iex(3)>
```

Comment: I had tried the spawning a process alternative before, but then when I would send back the result to the client with Process.send, the client wouldn't get the output on the terminal, and that is why I wasn't checking the mailbox! Thank you very much for your detailed response, I can see the light! I'll try with Task.start

Comment: *I can see the light!*--Good.  If the light doesn't go on all the way, I added a simple example.

Comment: Suppose the first example you've made. If you wouldn't want the client to be waiting, you would just create a process on the client side to do the receive? But then. you would have to also wait for that process response... hum maybe that wouldn't be possible?

Comment: @deko,  At some point the client will have to enter a receive to read the message.  At what point in time the client enters the receive, and how long the client waits in the receive are up to you.  On the other hand, with a Phoenix server there are things called `channels` that employ javascript to allow the server to inject the data into a web page when the data becomes available, and Phoenix has a new feature coming out called `LiveView`, which pretty much does the same thing without using javascript.